# Change mvtsplot in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I´m using mvtsplot (like in the example) with a time series dataset, but can´t change the default values on the y axis, which are 1:200 (with unit space). I´d like to use a 10 years interval scale. I tried with mtext but didn´t work; 
Thanks in advance for any help,
Maria D.

```
Tx = database[,1:200]
colnames(Tx) <- c(1:200)
mvtsplot(Tx, norm = "global", levels = 10, xtime = c(1940:2009))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late but it's the only question for 'mvtsplot' . 
If I understand well your question (and mvtsplot function) I think the y axis labels are controlled by the rownames of your Tx file

rownames(Tx) <- seq(0, 2000, by= 10)

HTH.